# Boost in Qt can't compiled in debug (C1083: No such file or directory) with MSVC

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, boost

I have compiled boost (version 1.62.0) with msvc compiler and boost works with Visual Studio 2015 debug and release version. But I can use boost with Qt (version 5.7) but only in release version, on debug version I have a example error:`C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/array.hpp': No such file or directory`.

It's my part of pro file:`INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost/boost_1_62_0
LIBS += -LC:/boost/boost_1_62_0/libs`.

Example project:

test.pro file

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = test
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost/boost_1_62_0
LIBS += -LC:/boost/boost_1_62_0/libs
```

main.cpp file

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

How to fix?

Comment: Add code that failed to compile.

Comment: Thanks. I added example project.

Comment: what's the actual compiler line that this results in (see compile output pane)

Comment: In line 2 --> #include <boost/array.hpp>

Comment: I mean, with what command line options is the compiler called on your main.cpp file. I.e. what do you get in the compile output pane when compiling the project.

Comment: Would it rather be `INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost/boost_1_62_0/include` ?

Comment: Thanks all. I changed the system to Ubuntu. And it works qt with boost on gcc compiler :-).